# Getting a sum of values in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have this R Shiny that gives me values of Meters covered based on the drill selected and the time selected by the user. Here is my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# MyData <- read.csv("/Users/sonamoravcikova/Desktop/ShinyTest/ForShiny1.csv")
MyData <- structure(list(Drill = c("GP Warm Up", "5v2 Rondo", "11v11",  "10v6 Drop
Behind Ball"), PlayerLoadPerMinute = c(7.72949670665213,  6.49382926701571,
9.67483408668731, 5.86770863636364), MetersPerMinute = c(69.9524820610687,
45.823744973822, 95.9405092879257, 58.185375), class = "data.frame", row.names
= c(NA,  -4L)))

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Practice Planner"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Select number of drills
      numericInput("num", h3("Number of Drills"), value = 1),
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      #Show boxes for the number of drill selected and select drill type
      selectInput("DrillName1",
                  label = "Choose a Drill:",
                  choices = unique(MyData$Drill),
                  selected = NULL,
                  multiple = FALSE),
      
      sliderInput("slider1", 
                  label = h3("Slider"), 
                  min = 0, 
                  max = 60, 
                  value = 0),
      textOutput("MpM1"),
      br(),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.num > '1'",
        selectInput("DrillName2",
                    label = "Choose a Drill:",
                    choices = unique(MyData$Drill),
                    selected = NULL,
                    multiple = FALSE),
        sliderInput("slider2", 
                    label = h3("Slider"), 
                    min = 0, 
                    max = 60, 
                    value = 0),
        textOutput("MpM2")),
      br(),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.num > '2'",
        selectInput("DrillName3",
                    label = "Choose a Drill:",
                    choices = unique(MyData$Drill),
                    selected = NULL,
                    multiple = FALSE),
        sliderInput("slider3", 
                    label = h3("Slider"), 
                    min = 0, 
                    max = 60, 
                    value = 0),
        textOutput("MpM3"))
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic  ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Calculate number of meters covered
  lapply(1:10, function(x) {
    output[[paste0("MpM", x)]] <- renderText({
      chosendrill <- input[[paste0("DrillName", x)]]
      MpM <- MyData %>%
        distinct(MetersPerMinute, .keep_all = T)
      MpM_text <- (MpM$MetersPerMinute[MpM$Drill == chosendrill]) * (input[[paste0("slider", x)]])
      paste0("Meters covered: ", paste0(MpM_text, collapse = " "))
    })
  })
}
  
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now I'm trying to just add all of the values that I get for the individual drills together so that I will get Meters covered for the whole session but I have no idea how to do that. So if someone could help me out where to start I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example by adding the output of `dput(MyData)` or `dput(head(MyData, 100))` to your question. Cheers

Comment: Hi, here is the output of MyData `structure(list(Drill = c("GP Warm Up", "5v2 Rondo", "11v11", 
"10v6 Drop Behind Ball"), PlayerLoadPerMinute = c(7.72949670665213, 
6.49382926701571, 9.67483408668731, 5.86770863636364), MetersPerMinute = c(69.9524820610687, 
45.823744973822, 95.9405092879257, 58.185375), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))`